# Paypal java REST API Refund.get response does not contain merchant fees

Tags: java, rest, paypal

I have successfully implemented refunds in my java app using the latest REST API but the response does not contain the 'Details' element held on the 'Amount' element so I can't determine the fee that was refunded and the handling fee charged.

I can look at the transactions in Paypal and see the total fee was refunded and the handling fee was 20p but the API doesn't seem to be returning that data?

Does anyone else see this?  Do I need to make a different call?  For now, i'm coding to 'assume' the fees were refunded, (if status=completed) and the handling fee was 20p, (as per the charging documentation) but it would be nice to get this back via the API.

Thanks.

Comment: As a last-case resort, you could always simply calculate it yourself. I believe their formula is publicly available.

Comment: Thanks QPaysTaxes, that's what i've done.  For full refunds the fee is 20p, (30 cents in the US) but I was expecting confirmation in the API.

Comment: I'd expect it to be confirmed in the API as well, but I guess they didn't think it necessary. I hope someone can help you.q